# Azure Storage Blob - Blob original properties

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to download a dll from Azure blobl storage and read its version.
When I download it by hand all the properties are there but when I download it with my code there is nothing:

[image: All properties gone]

This is the code I am using:

```cs
Stream file = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(downloadPath,blobName));
BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(connectionString, containerName, blobName);
blobClient.DownloadTo(file);
```

Comment: The size is 0. So does not seem you have downloaded it. Try:
`using Stream file = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(downloadPath,blobName));`

Comment: @Magnus I tried it with a "using" but still no properties. Its 32kb now and the original is 36kb

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and successfully downloaded dll files from azure blob storage.**

**Code:**

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;

namespace blobdll
{
    class program
    {
         public static void Main()
        {
            var connectionString = < Connection string>;
            var downloadPath = "< path of folder upto filename >";
            using Stream file = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(downloadPath));
            BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(connectionString, "test", "A2dLib-3.17.dll");
            blobClient.DownloadTo(file);
        }
    }
}
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Downloaded file:**

After downloaded file, I checked the size of the file it is in same size.

[image]